# Svelte: How do I access route parameters in page.svelte?

Tags: svelte

I am new to svelte. I have a route defined like this: `/posts/[slug]`. How do I access the `slug` in `page.svelte` file?

```
<script>
let slug = ...
</script>
```

I have tried searching [online](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+access+route+parameter+in+page.svelte) but cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would use the page store, which you can use from wherever in your app (pages or components)

```js
import { page } from '$app/stores';
let slug = $page.params.slug;
```